# How should a Facebook-Timeline system look on the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

How would I store Users "Posts"? So that I can efficiently get them from the db and then process them to display chronologically when a specific users page is requested?

Do I store all Posts from All Users in a single table like so:

```
Post ID | Poster ID | Post Content | Posted to this Users Wall | Post Timestamp
```

Then when a user opens UserFoo's Page I just get all rows where `Posted to this Users Wall = UserFoo`?

Wouldn't the sample above make a table bulky?

Comment: Make a separate table for Post Content and then another table for PostRelationships. One for Users as well (assuming you have one). Post Relationship should have like PostID, PosterID, PostPersonsWallID.

Comment: @raeq actually the actual table would have a relational database structure, what I was trying to point out is that "facebook has a billion users. All those post are stored in one table?" But of course parts of it are stored on a different table like the details of the post is one table, the destination is another, etc. but again "facebook has a billion users. All those post are stored in one table?"

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "posted to this Users wall " attribute ?  It just stores one "this user"? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout you propose looks reasonable.
5 columns (four `INT`'s and one `TEXT`), is not at all "bulky" a table.

If you have proper indexes, the query `WHERE "Posted to this Users Wall" = "UserFoo"` is virtually instant.

For your target query (display chronologically posts sent to the current user's wall), the best index is probably on `(Posted to this Users Wall, Post Timestamp)` (a two-columns index).

Answer (score 2):

`users`

```
id | name |
```

`posts`

```
|  id   |   u_id    |   content    |
```

`wall`

```
| id   |   u_id    |  post_id    |
```

u_id from `posts` is users.id where it's the Author

u_id from `wall` is users.id where it's the Target (on which wall is posted)

you can name it much more clear i.e. poster_id, target_id

---

Another way is to have

`post`

```
| id | poster_id |
```

`wall`

```
| id | post_id  | target_id |
```

`content`

```
|  post_id | content |
```

You can also add another specific things, such as if the post is a comment or something, in another table, or a column in `post` table

---

```
function getUsersWallPosts($target_id) {
    $query = "SELECT c.content FROM content AS c, INNER JOIN wall AS w ON w.post_id = c.post_id WHERE w.target_id = $target_id";
    $result = someUserDefinedFunctionForQueryAndFetch($query);
    return $result
}
```

Comment: +1 While extracting a separate `posts` entity offers more flexibility, I would consider moving the post contents in a separate table is an overkill.